# What's the difference between binding to [[var]] and {{var}} in Polymer 1.x?

Tags: data-binding, polymer, 2-way-object-databinding, polymer-1.0

I am familiar with bindings with curly braces, like `{{variable}}`, from Polymer 0.5.

However, in examples and code snippets for the release version of Polymer, I've begun to notice bindings with square brackets, such as `[[variable]]`, as well.

Does `{{variable}}` mean something different now, or is it the same and `[[variable]]` is just an addition? **What is the difference between binding to `[[variable]]` and `{{variable}}` in Polymer?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just as you've noticed, there are now two different syntaxes for data-binding, which have different purposes:

- **{{variable}}** indicates that you would like Polymer to automatically detect whether or not the binding should be **one-way or two-way**.
- **[[variable]]** indicates that you want the binding to **one-way only**.

### Why the change?

Polymer 1.x differs from older versions is that **bindings are now one-way by default**, much unlike 0.5, where they were always two-way.

In other words, if you write

```html
<my-element some-property="{{myVariable}}"></my-element>
```

then by default, when

- **myVariable is changed**, Polymer updates the binding, and thus updates `my-element`'s `someProperty`.
- **someProperty is changed**, Polymer does **not** update the binding to `myVariable`.

This is always the case **unless** you set `notify:true` on the property inside `my-element`:

```js
Polymer({
  is: 'my-element',
  properties: {
    someProperty: {
      notify: true,
      ...
```

With `notify: true`, the binding is now two-way, so when

- **myVariable is changed**, Polymer updates the binding to `someProperty`.
- **someProperty is changed**, Polymer **also** updates the binding to `myVariable`.

This behaviour (when using `notify: true`) used to be default in 0.5; now you must ask for it explicitly.

### When to use [[variable]]

There's no technical reason why you **must** use `[[variable]]`, because Polymer will automatically detect whether bindings are one or two-way with `{{variable}}`. So why would you use it?

Let's say you're working in a large project, and you know that based on the way that data flows in a particular page/element, a certain property should **never** be changed by the element it is being bound to, for example in the case of an element which functionally serves a purpose as a label:

```html
<display-data source-data="{{data}}"></display-data>
...
<data-editor source-data="{{data}}"></data-editor>
```

Everything looks good! The `data` property is bound to both the `display-data` element and `data-editor` elements, and will be automatically shared between them. (In this example, assume `display-data`'s sole purpose is to preview the data that it is bound to.)

One day, you or someone else is editing `display-data`, and you forget about the situation in which it is being used in above. For an entirely different use-case, you or the other developer would like `display-data` to also format or otherwise modify the data it is given and push it back towards any other elements that may be bound to it. You/they edit `display-data` as such:

- Add `notify: true` to `sourceData`, to allow two-way data-binding.
- Add code into `display-data` which modifies the `sourceData` property.

This works great for all the pages that needed this functionality. But on the page mentioned before, this was not intended and ends up garbling the data that `data-editor` sees!

This problem would have been avoided had:

- The dev team communicated better and had been more considerate of where elements are being used,
- and/or **[[data]]** was used instead of `{{data}}` in the page/element in question.

With

```html
<display-data source-data="[[data]]"></display-data>
...
<data-editor source-data="{{data}}"></data-editor>
```

`data-editor` can change `data`, but `display-data` will only ever be able to read `data`, and won't be able to change its value when it changes the value of its `sourceData` property, ***even when `notify: true` is set on `sourceData`***.

Therefore, it could potentially be a good idea to:

- Use **[[variable]]** whenever you need to bind to `variable`. This way, you enforce the direction through which data should flow in your element/page/application.
- Use **{{variable}}** whenever you *know* that the binding **must be two-way**.

According to [the documentation](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/migration.html#property-bindings),

> To make your code more easier to read, you may want to use the **[[property]]** form by default, and only use **{{property}}** for two-way bindings.

***This being said, however,*** it ultimately comes down to a matter of choice. *If you want to forego the use of `[[variable]]`, no one is stopping you and you will not start any fires.*